# csv export numbers not displaying correct

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

Hi I am exporting data to a .csv file. When I open the csv file my one column displays the data like this: 8.944E+19 when I double click on the text to see all the numbers I get this 89440000000014300000 but thats not correct this is the number in the database 89440000000014384616. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try exporting it as a text using single quote, then convert it into a number. That should work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719021/how-to-export-into-excel-formate-without-exponents might help you

Comment: Thanks found my answer: '="'.$row['column_name'].'"';

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue caused by the large numbers you are trying to use.

PHP uses floats, or signed 32-bit ints to store numbers. Clearly this is not enough. You can use arbitrary precision arithmetic to store these large numbers. See the PHP book on BC Math for more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php